# how to use conact in like query in ci

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have tbl_invoice.first_name and tbl_invoice.last_name as name, so want to search by name in Codeigniter with LIKE.
(example: first_name = Sanjib, last_name = Sarkar, name = Sanjib Sarkar . Search by "Sanjib Sarkar")

```
$this->db->select('tbl_invoice.*,tbl_members.*');
$this->db->from('tbl_invoice');
$this->db->join('tbl_members', 'tbl_members.id = tbl_invoice.member_id', 'left');
$this->db->like(CONCAT('tbl_invoice.first_name'." ".'tbl_invoice.last_name'), $search_value);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check value from first and last name using single like query

```
$this->db->select('tbl_invoice.*,tbl_members.*');
$this->db->from('tbl_invoice');
$this->db->join('tbl_members', 'tbl_members.id = tbl_invoice.member_id', 'left');
$this->db->like("(`first_name` LIKE '%m%' OR `last_name` LIKE '%m%')");
$query = $this->db->get();
```